# Validate a field on controller (as request body) but not on saving it in database

Tags: java, spring

I have the following entity class in my Spring boot project:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_account_entity")
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserAccountDeserializer.class)
public class UserAccountEntity implements UserDetails {

    private final static String ROLE_USER  = "ROLE_USER";

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String id;

    @NotBlank(message="Username cannot be empty")
    @Email(message="Username must be a valid email address")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message="Password cannot be empty")
    @Password
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity user;

    public UserAccountEntity(final String username, final String password) {
        this.password = password.trim();
        this.username = username.trim();
    }

    public UserAccountEntity() {}
    //setters and getters

}
```

and the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/authentication")
public class UserAccountControllerImpl implements UserAccountController {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountService userAccountService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public String create(@RequestBody UserAccountEntity userAccount,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = userAccount.getUsername();
        String password = userAccount.getPassword();
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        UserAccountEntity userAccount = new UserAccountEntity(username,
                    passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        userAccount.setUser(user);
        userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
        return userAccountService.authenticateUserAndSetResponsenHeader(
                username, password, response);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a custom validator for field `password`:

```
public class PasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Password, String> {
    public void initialize(Password constraintAnnotation) {}

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String trimmedValue = value.trim();
        if (trimmedValue.length() > 30 || trimmedValue.length() < 8) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Pattern.compile( "[0-9]" ).matcher(trimmedValue).find()) { // it doesn't contain any digit
            return false;
        }
        if (trimmedValue.toUpperCase().equals(trimmedValue)) { //it's all upper-case
            return false;
        }
        if (trimmedValue.toLowerCase().equals(trimmedValue)) { //it's all lower-case
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I validate the `password` field in the request body in the controller but not when saving it? As I encode that field when saving it, the validation does not pass when saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to use `@Valid` on the request body. So the new code change would look like this:

```
@Override
public String create (@Valid @RequestBody UserAccountEntity userAccount,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
}
```

After this you can use `InitBinder` to bind your custom validator:

```
@InitBinder
public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidator(new PasswordValidator());
}
```

Note that the method marked with `@InitBinder` is part of your `Controller` class.

Comment: Do I need to remove `@Password` from the field in the `UserAccountEntity` class? I have a `ExceptionHandlingController` defined as a `ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions thrown by validators. Do I still need to keep it?

Comment: If you are using `@InitBinder` to add validators, you do not need `@Password`