# Custom Jackson deserializer to throw exception if json doesn't contain required attributes

Tags: java

I have the following entity and deserializer in my Spring boot app:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_account_entity")
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserAccountDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = UserAccountSerializer.class)
public class UserAccountEntity implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public UserAccountEntity(final String username, final String password) {
        this.password = password.trim();
        this.username = username.trim();
    }
    //....
}

public class UserAccountDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<UserAccountEntity> {

    @Override
    public UserAccountEntity deserialize(JsonParser jp,
            DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        final String username = node.get("username").asText();
        final String password = node.get("password").asText();
        return new UserAccountEntity(username, password);
    }

}
```

If the json passed in the request body doesn't include any of the attributes `username` or `password`, a `NullPointerException` would be thrown. I want to change the exception to something more meaningful, like an instance of one of the classes that extend `JsonProcessingException`.

I have two questions: 
1. What classes extend `JsonProcessingException`? 
2. Is there a better way to check that expected attributes exist other than checking them one by one using `node.has`?

Comment: alternatively you can use bean validation @NotNull on a field and check if a UserAccountEntity valid with BindingResult

Comment: Because of what I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491232/validate-a-field-on-controller-as-request-body-but-not-on-saving-it-in-databas/52491435?noredirect=1#comment91925872_52491435 I don't want to use field level checks.

Comment: i dont get it. if the bindingresult contains errors, do not encode the password and do not save it ?

Comment: I have an exception handling advice, if I annotate the required fields with `@NotNull`, that handler doesn't catch the exceptions, right?

Comment: There aren’t any exceptions. NotNull doesn’t throw an exception on deserialization

Comment: I'm looking for a way to throw exception.

Comment: You can throw it in the controller. If binding result has errors, throw a jsonparsing exception

Comment: I don't like to repeat that in each controller.